# Order of an element in Symmetric Group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Given $σ$ in $S_7$ where,
$$σ=(14532)(67)$$
I know that this order of this element is $5$ as $σ^5=Id.$ I originally thought that the order of the element would be 10 as $lcm(5,2)=10$. Could someone please explain why this isn't the case?

Comment: The order is $\;lcm(2,5)=10\;$ . Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: $\sigma^5=(67)\neq Id$

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now. There must be a mistake in the marking scheme for a past exam i'm going through. Confused me into making the same mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Your theory is right, and your calculation is wrong. We have
$$
\sigma^5 = (67)
$$

Comment: Thank you! just a silly miscalculation...